# How to calculate desired light path in continuous medium with gradient refraction index

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, variational-calculus

See the Figure below.

$O:(0,0)$ is the disk center of light source $\odot{O}$ with radius $3$.

Then the **profile** light rays of disk $O$ from the view point $B:(-14,0)$ is defined by segments $DB$ and $EB$ (also the tangent lines of $\odot{O}$ through $B$) when the refraction index is a constant value everywhere.

Now if the refraction index is defined as:

$$n(x,y)=\dfrac{e^{\tfrac{(x+15)^2+y^2+12}{(x+15)^2+y^2+11}}}{e}$$

How to determine the two **profile** light curves of disk $O$ from the viewpoint $B$?

[image]

I tried to establish:

$$\delta\int{n(x,y)}\rm{d}s=0$$ 
and the second order nonlinear ODE via Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$y''(x)=\dfrac{2\left((x+15)y'(x)-y(x)\right)\left(y'(x)^2+1\right)}{\left(y(x)^2+x(x+30)+236\right)^2}$$
but don't know how to establish initial/boundary values of the ordinary differential equation and obtain a symbolic or numerical solution.

**Update**

Since $y(-14)=0$ is easily available, actually my question is only `how to determine another' $y'(-14)=?$ such that the ODE can be easily solved numerically?

**Update**

I tried some calculation, and it seems, for any numerical solution $y(x)$, it will be difficult to determine whether it is tangent to the circle $O$ or not:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It appears to me that you want to know the path along which the light travels from point D to point B, where D is defined as to be on the edge of the red circle and perpendicular to the path, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. Even when $D$ is a fixed point as defined in the figure, the ODE will become a boundary value problem and is more difficult than the ODE with both initial and boundary value conditions.

Comment: Would it be easier to change to a radial coordinate system centered at (-15,0)? Then 

$$n(r) = e^{\frac{r^2+2}{r^2+1}-1}$$

Comment: It seems coordinate transformation does not make it easier; the key issue lies in solving the 2nd order nonlinear ODE obtained (with boundary value conditions)

Comment: Why votes for close? The OP didn't ask to solve his problem, he/she asked for some guidance. Those who voted for close, know how to solve? Then give a hand of help!

Comment: I think you are dismissing Floris' idea to quickly. I think it will make the ODE a lot easier to solve. I have not worked with the Euler-Lagrangian equation for years and am blacking out on it so I am not able to do it right now, though...

Comment: Thank you Sofia! Since one of the boundary value condition $y(-14)=0$ is easily available, what I need is only how to determine another $y'(-14)=?$, then the ODE will be easy to solve.

Comment: Well, you have a boundary condition for y' at D, of course, but I don't know if that helps as the position of D depends on the solution for y...

Comment: Yes you're right. The `D` depends on $n(x,y)$. That is why I think $y'(-14)$ is a better choice. A compromise might be: first give an initial guess of $y'(-14)$ then determine $y(x)$ and see whether it is tangent to the circle, then give a $\delta$ to the guess of $y'(-14)$ and continue the iteration until the obtained $y(x)$ is tengent to the cirle.

Comment: How did you get that last image?

Comment: See the contour lines, I changed the $n(x,y)$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change to a radial coordinate system. You basically have an index profile of n(r) = e^(r2-A)/(r2-B). I don't know where you get this type of gradient profile. It is the first time I have seen it. Typically we consider gradient geometries of axial, radial, spherical, parabolic and such. But the path of the light from the center of your right sphere will curve through the sphere and when it exits, it will go in a straight line. I find your figure confusing. You seem to have a point source of light at the center of the left hand circle yet your text says that the light source is at O (center of the right side circle). I do not understand exactly what you are trying to do. Are you saying that your gradient index is inside the circle on the right and there is a point source at the center? Can you please be more specific about the set up. Also, light ALWAYS goes from left to right. It's a Law dude! So when you draw it, your light source should be on the left. It's just convention. Looking forward to more info. I've been working with gradient index glass for 25 years. I developed GRADIUM while at LightPath Technologies. Large scale axial gradient index glass.

Comment: The red disk on the right hand side is actually the light source. I was interested in the intersection angle of upper and lower light rays (not a point light source, but a disk like the sun)when they met each other on the surface of the left disk.